# Redirect http request to mailto request

Tags: php, http, email, zend-framework, mailto

I want to have links in my page that redirect to a mailto.  I am doing this to gather statistics on clicks.  I have this call in my controller action and it does redirect as expected:

```
$this->getHelper('Redirector')->gotoUrl('mailto://' . $email_address);
```

The problem that I'm having is that it displays a blank page as well as spawning the application registered to the mailto protocol.  Is there a way to avoid the blank page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't you just use a regular mailto link, and attach a JavaScript event handler to the link which would send an ajax request to the server to update the statistics? You would of course lose statistics when Javascript is disabled.

Another alternative is to set the target of the link to an iframe, so that it's the iframe which becomes blank. If the iframe is invisible, the problem of the blank page becomes invisible as well.

Comment: I really like the iframe idea!  I'm going to give it a whirl.

Comment: The iframe works perfectly. I like it because it doesn't rely on JavaScript.

Comment: There are a few problems with using an iframe. For example, if your browser is setup to automatically start a new message in Gmail with mailto: then it doesn't work at all! Possibly a mostly blank page with a link to go back and with a meta-redirect and JavaScript redirect.